# Flutter Build AAB crashes due to RXLogs

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, build, android-app-bundle

I'm having trouble building AAB for Android with Flutter.

When I write this command : flutter build appbundle
It throws this [ErrorImage]

This project I'm working on, is already on the store, and they ask me to add stuffs, and now I'm trying to build to update the app but this error always appears.

We're not using RxLogs and we've removed it from pubspec.yaml, but in the puspec.lock it appears when running : flutter pub get

Thanks for your answers

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1xUj.png)

I've tried : flutter build appbundle

Shows error above

Comment: Have you tried with release build?

Answer (score 0):

> We're not using RxLogs and we've removed it from pubspec.yaml, but in
> the puspec.lock it appears when running : flutter pub get

You can follow these below steps:

1 - Delete Podfile.lock

2 - In terminal, enter "cd ios"

3 - Continue to enter "pod install --repo-update"

4 - "cd .."

5 - flutter clean

6 - flutter pub get

7 - build the project again

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

For resolving for Android, the steps are as follows:

- delete pubspec.lock file **not pubspec.yaml**
- run flutter clean
- run flutter pub get
- cd android
- ./gradlew clean

Try to build your Android apk. In case you encounter any error related to kotlin, update to latest kotlin version in the android/build.gradle. Finally build APK.

Hope this will be help you.